# How is velocity at any point in a laminar flow constant in if the velocity profile in a laminar flow is parabolic?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow

Our lecturer said that velocity at any point in laminar flow is constant. But in another lecture slide (about flow velocity profiles), he also wrote that not all fluid particles travel at the same velocity and that in laminar flow, the velocity distribution at a cross-section will be parabolic in shape with the maximum velocity at the center being about twice the average velocity in the pipe. So how is the velocity then constant at any point in laminar flow? I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't make sense of the two statements together.

Edit: Thank you for the answer, I understand now what I wasn't seeing.

Comment: There is a difference between "uniform" and "constant". See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/540983/258881) which is written in another physical context, however the same definitions also translate over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the terms "constant" and "uniform". When one says that "velocity at any point in laminar flow is constant", it means that the velocity of all the fluid particles passing through that point is constant **over time**. However, when one says that the "velocity is unifom", that is when we conclude that the velocity of the particles is the same **over space** and the velocity profie is the same everywhere.